# Critical/saddle point/Minimum of $f(x,y)= x^2y+y^3-12y$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Below is the question I need help with:
[image]

I keep trying to solve it however I do not know what I am doing wrong! I have one more shot at the question online. This is what I am doing:

$$f(x,y)= x^2y+y^3-12y$$
$$f_x = 2xy$$
$$f_y= x^2+3y^2-12$$

$x^2+3y^2-12$ at $x =0$   --> $3y^2=0$ --> $y=+2$ and $-2$
Therefore, my critical points are $(0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$

Now in order to find the answers below, I need to do the second derivative test

$f_{xx}=2y$
$f_{yy}= 6y$    and I used this equation $D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2$

$$D= (2y\cdot 6y)-(2x)^2 = 12y^2-4x^2$$

And when I plugged in the values like the critical points and $(0,0)$ I get the answers below but I do not know what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like your critical point calculation is incorrect; you want the points where $f_x=0$ _and_ $f_y=0$, and while $x=0$ implies that $f_x=0$, that's not the only way of getting $f_x=0$...

Answer (score 3):

We have to find the points where we simultaneously have $f_x = f_y = 0$

Given:

$$f(x,y)= x^2y+y^3-12y$$

We have:
$$f_x = 2xy = 0$$
$$f_y= x^2+3y^2-12 = 0 $$

The first equation leads to $x = 0 $ or $y = 0$, thus we have four potential critical points to investigate and those are:

$$(x, y) = (0, -2), (0, 2), (-2~ \sqrt{3}, 0), (2~ \sqrt{3}, 0)$$

Can you continue?

The tests you need to use for 'each' critical point are decribed [*here*](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/min_max/min_max.html).

Here is a plot and also a contour plot of the function.

[image]

[image]

You should arrive at a local min and local max, but no global min or max.

Comment: Would't I have to plug in the critical points into 12y^2−4x^2 now? And see what the result is? If it is less than 0 then it is seen as a saddle point, and if it is more than 0 then it is a local maximum?

Comment: @SherryEskandarian: Yes, you would test each critical point by plugging $(x, y)$ values into $D$ and then testing the result against the If statements on the link.